# AP Physics: Continuity of electric potential for an infinite sheet

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential

[image]

For the mcq question above, the answer key states that the  potential is continous and the electric field is discontinuous.

I understand how the electric field is discontinuous as it points in 1 direction for 1 side of the sheet, then jumps to point in the other direction for the other side of the sheet.

What I don't get: How does that show the potential is continuous? The textbook/answer key says that since $E = -dV/dr$, this implies that the potential is also continuous. I can't seem to understand as to why this is the case as all this tells me is that since the electric field is constant, the potential is a straight line with a slope of say $m$ for 1 side of the plate, the other side of the plate would have a potential of $-m$. How does this show me that potential is continuous (especially at the origin)?

Comment: Two comments.  Is this AP Physics C?  Have you tried plotting electric potential vs. position?

Comment: Indeed this is AP Physics C. I have not tried to plot it, rather there was a plot already but their explanation didn't really make sense to me.

Comment: hint: integrate any discontinuous (finite) function, is the integral continuous?

Comment: @michael, a continuous function does not have any "jumps" in it.  However, a continuous function is not always differentiable, as it could contain a sharp change in direction at some points, whereby you would get a different slope from a derivative depending on whether you approached that point from the left or the right.  You can get such information from looking at the plot.

Comment: @DavidWhite I understand that I can get it by looking at the plot however I was unsure on how they got the plot in the first place, especially at the point x = 0 where the electric field switches directions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a good conceptual question here. I'm going to try to pitch this explanation at a level that is probably slightly higher than what is covered in AP Physics C, but that hopefully you can follow (let me know if not). This is an area where pursuing your question can lead you deeper into the subject than what you are expected to know on the test.

In a sense you are right. If you remove the sheet itself at the origin, then you can think of the two sides of the sheet separately. The potential is only defined up to a constant, so you could add different constants to the two sides, and the potential would not be continuous at the sheet. But the field would be the same everywhere on either side of the sheet, as it would be if the potential were continuous.

So, clearly, grokking the difference between these cases relies on understanding what's happening exactly at the sheet, which is quite a singular place and tricky to get a handle on

One physical way to understand what is going on is to imagine fuzzing out the infinitely thin sheet into a slab with a finite thickness. It is possible to solve for the field and potential inside a slab, although I don't remember if you do it in AP Physics C or not. The field continuously goes to zero at the center of the slab, and then changes direction. Because the field is continuous, the potential  is also continuous (and differentiable). Then, in the limit that the slab becomes infinitely thin and becomes a sheet, the potential will remain continuous. Since the infinitely thin sheet is really just an idealization for a charge distribution with a small-but-finite thickness, we should expect on physical grounds that the potential of a sheet should be continuous, based on this limit.

We can also probe the sheet more directly, at the cost of some mathematical abstraction. In particular, the underlying mathematical fact here is that the derivative of a discontinuous function is *more singular* at the discontinuity, than the derivative of a function with a non-differentiable kink is at the kink. This can be made precise in terms of the [Dirac delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function), which I suspect you haven't met but you will if you continue studying physics. The derivative of a [step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Step_function) is a delta function. The delta function is a "function" (actually a distribution, but that's a detail at this level) which is zero everywhere except a single point, where it is infinitely large. If the potential is discontinuous at a point, then the electric field will be proportional to a delta function at that point. This means that there would be an *infinitely strong* electric field at the surface of the sheet, which is a singularity pointing to a breakdown of Maxwell's equations.

Even without knowing about Dirac delta functions, you can detect the difference between a continuous and a discontinuous potential, by integrating the electric field, as suggested in the comments by hypnortex. If you integrate the electric field of a sheet, you will get a continuous potential. In order for the integral to be discontinuous at the origin, the field must be infinitely large there.

Comment: Aren't these all arguments against the electric field being discontinuous?

Comment: @DKNguyen No. The electric field *can* be discontinuous across a surface charge distribution (actually it must be). The point is that if the *potential* is discontinuous, then the field is *singular* -- that is a big problem. The slab argument also makes it clear why the potential needs to be continuous.

Comment: The slab reasoning also seems to make the field continuous though. You do say "*The field continuously goes to zero at the center of the slab, and then changes direction. Because the field is continuous...*"

Comment: In the limit that the slab thickness goes to zero, the field changes discontinuously but the potential is continuous.

Comment: That doesn't feel right that something is remains continuous as you squeeze it towards zero but then suddenly becomes discontinuous at zero (assuming you can actually get to zero). I interpreted your phrasing as it continuously approaches the same field value (zero) from both sides as it approaches the center of the plate so I don't see why there would suddenly be a discontinuity at the limit. Unless it doesn't smoothly approach a field value of zero before reversing direction?

Comment: @DKNguyen "That doesn't feel right that something is remains continuous as you squeeze it towards zero but then suddenly becomes discontinuous at zero" -- It's fairly easy to see that this feeling would lead you to make incorrect statements purely mathematically. Consider the function $\tanh(k x)$. In the limit $k \rightarrow 0$, this function is discontinuous at $x=0$. Or, consider the piecewise linear function that is equal to $-Y$ from $-\infty$ to $-a$, the line $Y x/a$ from $-a$ to $a$, and equal to $Y$ from $a$ to $\infty$. This function is discontinuous in the limit $a\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: One way to understand the limit with the slab is to think that in the limit, it is as if you are removing the space containing the slab and gluing the space on either side of the slab together. That might make it easier to see why there's a discontinuity in the field -- the limit is getting rid of the region where the field continuously changes.

Comment: Is that what the limit does? I tend to imagine the limit as "zooming in". Functions like tanh(kx) do exist, sure. What's type of function describes what the field looks like in the plate?

Comment: The real point is that the limit is singular. *Physically*, nothing is ever truly singular, so the slab is a more realistic model in some sense. However, it is mathematically very useful to be able to treat these singular cases, because (a) they are easier to solve, and (b) it helps us establish that nothing really depends on the details of how we model the surface (a slab is also not a particularly realistic model of surface charge, really). So there is something funny happening in the limit.

Comment: The piecewise linear function I described is actually what happens in the slab.

Comment: It's more like "zooming out" in this case, until the thickness of the slab becomes zero.

Comment: Hmmmm. Yes that piecewise function x/a does have an abruptness right at zero.

Comment: This is essentially an example of non-uniform convergence. Limits are tricky!

Comment: This is starting to remind me of contradictions that prevent ideal scenarios from being physically realizable. Like in EE when beginners ask what happens when they connect two ideal voltage sources in parallel. I know why it doesn't work in reality so I can use the idealized case but I'm not quite familiar with it here so I don't know of any contradictions that explain why an infinitely thin sheet can't exist other than the notion something infinitely thin isn't real.

Comment: @DKNguyen Yeah it's a fair point to ask why we need these singular idealizations when we know they aren't physical. But being able to deal with singular surface charges is very useful -- it lets us set up boundary value problems (and apply them to real problems). Also, physically, it should be the case that the details of how the surface charge is distributed in the "small" spatial dimension don't matter if you are far from the surface. The fact that the limit can be taken in a consistent way is tied to this fact (if different kinds of slabs gave different answers that would be weird!)